# Nodejs - cannot upload file using multer via ajax

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, multer

I have a form which contains both text fields and an input file field. For some reasons, all the data went through without any error but the file. Can anyone suggest a fix? Thanks.

**index.ejs**

```
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' onsubmit="create_ajax('/create_restaurant')">
    <input type="file" id="restaurantProfilePicture" name="restaurantPicture" accept="images/*"><br>
```

**Front end Javascript**

```
function create_ajax(url) {
var formArray= $("form").serializeArray();
var data={};
for (index in formArray){
    data[formArray[index].name]= formArray[index].value;
}

$.ajax({
    url: url ,
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (dataR) {
        console.log(dataR)
        if (dataR.hasOwnProperty('message')){
            document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = dataR.message;
        }else{
            window.location.replace('/restaurant?restaurantid=' + dataR.restaurant_ID);
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.log('Error: ' + error.message);
    }
});
event.preventDefault();
}
```

**Back-end, route/index.js**

```
var multer = require('multer');
var restaurantProfileName = "";

var storageRestaurantProfile = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './public/images/restaurant_profile_images')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        // random token generation to avoid duplicated file name
        var random_token = "";
        var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++){
            random_token += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
        }
        restaurantProfileName = random_token + "-" + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname); // get file extension
        cb(null, restaurantProfileName)
    }
})

var restaurantProfileUpload = multer({ storage: storageRestaurantProfile });

router.post('/create_restaurant', restaurantProfileUpload.single("restaurantPicture"), function (req, res) {
```

Comment: You haven't included your HTML. However, the most common reason for this issue is the lack of updating a form to `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Please provide the form information and the shortest code necessary to reproduce.

Comment: I have like 20 fields in the form and most of them are text fields. I can get all the information from the form except the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To upload files via ajax you use a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object, just pass the form you want to upload to the constructor and set contentType and processData to false in $.ajax.

```
function create_ajax(url) {
    var fd = new FormData($("form").get(0));    
    $.ajax({
        url: url ,
        data: fd,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (dataR) {
            console.log(dataR)
            if (dataR.hasOwnProperty('message')){
                document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = dataR.message;
            }else{
                window.location.replace('/restaurant?restaurantid=' + dataR.restaurant_ID);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.log('Error: ' + error.message);
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
}
```